# How to limit access to woocommerce REST API?

Tags: android, wordpress, rest, woocommerce

I am trying to make call to `woocommerce` REST API from my android app , but the issue is that it exposes all APIs available in woocommerce , like `removing` a product which is a security issue.now the question is how can i limit access to APIs so that the app be able to call the specific set of APIs, for example only `getProductList()` from product APIs.